# Gradle doesn't shows dagger2 component graph anymore after update

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dagger-2, gradle-plugin

Recently, I have updated the Gradle version and gradle plugin to: 
4.6 and 3.1.1. Now, when I try to compile projects that have some dependency problems gradle only points an compilation error saying it cannot find class DaggerApplicationComponent.

Before, when there was a dagger dependency problem, it showed what dependency was no satisfied and the dependency tree. Like:

```
"Dagger 2 cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method"

"Error:(51, 10) error: .BaseActivity cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method. BaseActivity is injected at AppComponent.inject(baseActivity) Error:(75, 10) error: MainActivity cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method. MainActivity is injected at .AppComponent.inject(mainActivity)"
```

Now it shows this:

[image]

[image]

The dependency that is not satisfied came from a class in an java library. Its gradle file is:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'net.ltgt.apt'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.15'

    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.15'


    api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'

    api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.4.0'


    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.6.0'

    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.12'


    api 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.5.0'
    /*implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'*/



}
sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
targetCompatibility = "1.8"
```

the root gradle file is:

```
// Top-level build file whesugre you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }



}



plugins {
    id "net.ltgt.apt" version "0.15"

}

allprojects {


    repositories {
        jcenter()

        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        google()
    }



}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


Android Studio 3.1.1
Build #AI-173.4697961, built on April 3, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.14.0-deepin2-amd64
```

Is there any additional configuration required?

---

EDIT:

For now I solve it running the build via command line.

./gradlew build

and it shows:

```
home/alexandre/dev/projetos/gitlab/BeerCollection/app/src/main/java/com/github/alexpfx/udacity/beercollection/dagger/ApplicationComponent.java:22: error: [com.github.alexpfx.udacity.beercollection.dagger.HomeSubComponent.inject(com.github.alexpfx.udacity.beercollection.ui.home.HomeFragment)] com.github.alexpfx.udacity.beercollection.databaselib.search.BeerRemoteDataSource cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public interface ApplicationComponent {
       ^
      com.github.alexpfx.udacity.beercollection.databaselib.search.BeerRemoteDataSource is injected at
          com.github.alexpfx.udacity.beercollection.favorite.FavoriteInteractorImpl.<init>(…, beerRemoteDataSource)
      com.github.alexpfx.udacity.beercollection.favorite.FavoriteInteractorImpl is injected at
          com.github.alexpfx.udacity.beercollection.dagger.FavoriteModule.providesFavoriteInteractor(favoriteInteractor)
      com.github.alexpfx.udacity.beercollection.favorite.FavoriteInteractor is injected at
          com.github.alexpfx.udacity.beercollection.databaselib.search.DefaultSearchPresenter.<init>(…, arg2)
      com.github.alexpfx.udacity.beercollection.databaselib.search.DefaultSearchPresenter is injected at
          com.github.alexpfx.udacity.beercollection.dagger.SearchModule.searchPresenter(searchPresenter)
      com.github.alexpfx.udacity.beercollection.databaselib.search.SearchPresenter is injected at
          com.github.alexpfx.udacity.beercollection.ui.home.HomeFragment.searchPresenter
      com.github.alexpfx.udacity.beercollection.ui.home.HomeFragment is injected at
          com.github.alexpfx.udacity.beercollection.dagger.HomeSubComponent.inject(homeFragment)
2 errors
```

I could not get it to show on the build tab, but for me it's okay

Comment: IIRC There should be some tab called "Logs" or similar where you find the full gradle output. The output will also include any errors

Comment: there is an Event log tab, but it doesn't shows the dependency graph

Answer (score 4):

You can find the gradle output when clicking `Toggle View` on the Build tab.

[image]